# Zoom in or out with trackpad stops working

Tags: trackpad, multi-touch

I am using OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 (15G1217) on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015).

Sometimes when reading PDF's I notice I suddenly can not use the trackpad zoom feature anymore. It is not related to PDF's in general, as both in the apps Skim, Preview and Scapple it has stopped working.

If it had stopped working, multi-touch features such as Mission Control still work, suggesting the problem is not hardware.

When I disable and then re-enable the 'Zoom in or out' feature (cf. figure), it suddenly works again. How can I troubleshoot this problem?
[image: Disable and then re-enable to fix]

Comment: I have the exact same issue but with Swipe back and forward gestures in Web browsers. No permanent solution so far.

Comment: @stevyhacker I think that by updating to macOS Sierra, the bug was solved. Currently I am using macOS Mojave and I don't experience this erratic trackpad behavior anymore.

Comment: I am on Mojave and I still experience it on Chrome a few times a month, glad it was solved for you.

Comment: I'm on High Sierra and I also get this kind of problems once in a while.

Comment: I used to have the same problem on my MacBook Pro. It turned out it was an app that caused it occasionally. If it's not too much to ask, please let me know what apps you have installed and if any of them are cracked (for research purposes only, obviously ;)).

Comment: @thaikolja sorry I can't answer your request, as I switched to using free open source software instead of apple, so my old macbook is collecting dust ;)